# Visual Studio Code error "/bin/sh: 1: powershell: not found"

Tags: powershell

I get the error "/bin/sh: 1: powershell: not found" in the OUTPUT tab in Visual Studio Code Version 1.53.0 when i try to run simple script in a new file which is open in the editor.

does the "**which pwsh**" output "/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh" have anything to do with this? Maybe the path.

[image: error "/bin/sh: 1: powershell: not found"]

And as a result the PROBLEMS tab outputs:
[image: PROBLEMS tab outputs]

some extra details:
PS /home/arend/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0/examples> **which pwsh**
/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh

PS /home/arend/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0/examples> **$PSVersionTable**
Name Value
PSVersion 7.1.1
PSEdition Core
GitCommitId 7.1.1
OS Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021
Platform Unix
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion 3.0

**Visual Studio Code**
Version: 1.53.0
Commit: 8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496
Date: 2021-02-03T15:56:04.185Z
Electron: 11.2.1
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-65-generic

Comment: Before version 6, the executable is called `powershell.exe` (which is what the screenshot shows). As of version 6, it is called `pwsh.exe`. Looks like you are trying to call the wrong version here

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you very much for the clarification. It looks like the problem was solved after re-installing VScode from scratch. I am trying to find where in the settings i can see what PowerShell file it points to. Do you know?

Comment: Sure, have a look here [Configure default PowerShell version](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/configure-visual-studio-code-to-run-powershell-for-windows-and/ba-p/283258) for instance. By modifying the `settings.json`, you can determine which PowerShell version should be default.

Comment: settings.json. thank you Theo